# Spring Boot API : If any field is empty in request body it is storing as null in DB

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, entity, mongodb-java

If any field is empty in request body it is storing as null in DB, that is because of entity class I guess.
For example : if in entity class a field is there as "name".
My question is if I am not passing that "name" attribute  in request body it should not store null in DB. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)** *Jackson annotation* on entity level or attribute level to ignore the empty or null values when serializing json.

Comment: Welcome Avinash Thakur.